# wget ssl alert handshake failure

Tags: ssl, https, wget

I am trying to download files from an https site and keep getting the following error:

```
OpenSSL: error:14077410:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:sslv3 alert handshake failure
Unable to establish SSL connection.
```

From reading blogs online I gather I have to provide the server cert and the client cert. I have found steps on how to download the server cert but not the client cert. Does anyone have a complete set of steps to use wget with SSL? I also tried the --no-check-certificate option but that did not work.

```
wget version: wget-1.13.4
openssl version: OpenSSL 1.0.1f 6 Jan 2014
```

trying to download all lecture resources from a course's webpage on coursera.org. So, the URL would look something like this: https://class.coursera.org/matrix-002/lecture

Accessing this webpage online requires form authentication, not sure if that is causing the failure.

Comment: This could be anything, like unsupported protocol, ciphers, SNI .... . But it is usually unrelated to validation of server certificate. Please add more details like version of wget, version of openssl and site you are trying to access. Also use `wget -v --debug`.

Comment: please help me solve this. i will be very grateful.
https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/240008/unsupported-protocol-ssl-c1124

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? In a standard issue SSL/TLS configuration, the server certificate would be supplied by the server during handshake, and there would be no client cert.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

It works from here with same OpenSSL version, but a newer version of wget (1.15). Looking at the Changelog there is the following significant change regarding your problem:

> 1.14: Add support for TLS Server Name Indication.

Note that this site does not require SNI. But `www.coursera.org` requires it.
And if you would call wget with `-v --debug` (as I've explicitly recommended in my comment!) you will see:

```
$ wget https://class.coursera.org
...
HTTP request sent, awaiting response...
  HTTP/1.1 302 Found
...
Location: https://www.coursera.org/ [following]
...
Connecting to www.coursera.org (www.coursera.org)|54.230.46.78|:443... connected.
OpenSSL: error:14077410:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:sslv3 alert handshake failure
Unable to establish SSL connection.
```

So the error actually happens with `www.coursera.org` and the reason is missing support for SNI. You need to upgrade your version of wget.

Comment: Never thought of updating wget. Thanks for the hint!

Comment: So, if we're working on a RHEL 6 server as a user with no possibility of upgrading *any* package, how do we overcome such an issue?

Comment: @Vitor: if you are using an up-to-date version of RHEL 6 you are using wget-1.12-10.  According to [this](https://rpmfind.net/linux/RPM/centos/6.9/x86_64/Packages/wget-1.12-10.el6.x86_64.html) support for SNI was backported to wget-1.12-4 in 2014. If it does not work for you it might be a different problem so you should create a new question with enough details.

Comment: It works. I have to upgrade to wget 1.21 version.

Answer (score 9):

You probably have an old version of wget. I suggest installing wget using [Chocolatey](https://chocolatey.org/), the package manager for Windows. This should give you a more recent version (if not the latest).

Run this command after having installed Chocolatey (as Administrator):

```
choco install wget
```

Comment: This worked, but was confusing. I had to upgrade my wget, but I had to upgrade from administrator console. This should be mentioned. As should be that the user does not need to run the chocolatey powershell wget. The install adds both a powershell wget wrapper and the binary. For this reason it's a bit unclean

Answer (score 3):

I was in SLES12 and for me it worked after upgrading to wget 1.14, using --secure-protocol=TLSv1.2 and using --auth-no-challenge.

```
wget --no-check-certificate --secure-protocol=TLSv1.2 --user=satul --password=xxx --auth-no-challenge -v --debug https://jenkins-server/artifact/build.x86_64.tgz
```

Comment: `--secure-protocol` can be `auto`, `SSLv2`, `SSLv3` or `TLSv1`. There is no option `TLSv1.2`

Comment: But there is an option `--secure-protocol=TLSv1_2`. I guess it was just a typo.

Comment: wget: --secure-protocol: Invalid value `TLSv1_2'.

Answer (score 3):

One alternative is to replace the "https" with "http" in the url that you're trying to download from to just circumvent the SSL connection.  Not the most secure solution, but this worked in my case.

Comment: For many websites, it redirects again to https

Answer (score 1):

I was having this problem on Ubuntu 12.04.3 LTS (well beyond EOL, I know...) and got around it with:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install ca-certificates
```

Answer (score 1):

Otherwise might be just simpler to use curl instead.
There is no peculiar need to specify any option and can be simply:

```
curl https://example.com/filename.zip
```

with curl there is no need to add the -v option when facing the wget SSL error.

Comment: This has already been suggested https://stackoverflow.com/a/58748631/13525512

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.

Answer (score 0):

Basically your OpenSSL uses SSLv3 and the site you are accessing does not support that protocol.

Just update your wget:

`sudo apt-get install wget`

Or if it is already supporting another secure protocol, just add it as argument:

`wget https://example.com --secure-protocol=PROTOCOL_v1`

Answer (score 0):

Below command for download files from TLSv1.2 website.

curl -v --tlsv1.2 https://example.com/filename.zip

It`s worked!